# Obtain key from array through value

Tags: php

How can I obtain a key in a array just by knowing it's value? For example, here is an array:

```
$array = Array("Item1" => array("Number" => "One", "Letter" => "A"));
```

Just by knowing "One" or "A", how can I get the main key name, `Item1`?

I've looked into `array_key_value` and `in_array` but I do not think that those functions are helpful for my kind of array.

Comment: WIth a `foreach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a 2d array, you will want to search the inner array for the value so you would have to make your own function to do this. Something like this:

```
function findInArray($array, $lookup){
    //loop over the outer array getting each key and value.
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        //if we found our lookup value in the inner array
        if(in_array($lookup, $value)){
            //return the original key
            return $key;
        }
    }
    //else, return null because not found
    return null;
}

$array = Array("Item1" => array("Number" => "One", "Letter" => "A"));

var_dump(findInArray($array, 'One')); //outputs string(5) "Item1"
var_dump(findInArray($array, 'Two')); //outputs null
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/oRjHK

Answer (score 0):

This function may help you

```
function key_of_value($array, $value){
    foreach($array as $key=>$val){
        if(in_array($value, $val)){
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

echo key_of_value(['Item1'=>['One','Two','Three','Hello',2,6]],'A');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around iterating through your data. This might be a little more elegant than two `foreach` loops:

```
<?php
$match = null;
$needle = 'Two';
$haystack = [
    'Item1' => [
        'Number' => 'One',
        'Letter' => 'A'
    ],
    'Item2' => [
        'Number' => 'Two',
        'Letter' => 'B'
    ],
    'Item3' => [
        'Number' => 'Three',
        'Letter' => 'C'
    ],
];

array_walk($haystack, function($entry, $key) use ($needle, &$match) {
    if(in_array($needle, $entry)) {
        $match = $key;
    }
});
var_dump($match);
```

The output obviously is:

```
string(5) "Item2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to iterate on array values recursive. I write a function that return main key of searched value in nested arrays.

```
<?php

$array = array("Item1" => array("Number" => "One", "Letter" => "A", 'other' => array('Number' => "Two")));

echo find_main_key($array, 'One'); //Output: "Item1"
echo find_main_key($array, 'A'); //Output: "Item1"
echo find_main_key($array, 'Two'); //Output: "Item1"
var_dump(find_main_key($array, 'nothing')); // NULL

function find_main_key($array, $value) {
    $finded_key = NULL;
    foreach($array as $this_main_key => $array_item) {
        if(!$finded_key) {
            array_walk_recursive($array_item, function($inner_item, $inner_key) use ($value, $this_main_key, &$finded_key){
                if($inner_item === $value) {
                    $finded_key = $this_main_key;
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
    }
    return $finded_key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

`foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array('One', $value)) echo  $key;
}`